# Excel VBA - Refresh specific Pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am using the code below to refresh a pivot table, which is in another worksheet but in the same workbook, not sure what I am missing because it only works if I run it within Sales worksheet. I thought that using the whole object's hierarchy that would work. Any suggestion?

```
Sub RefreshSales()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").PivotTables(1).RefreshTable
    MsgBox "Refresh completed", vbInformation
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you placing the code in a code module within the same workbook as the Sales sheet? If so, use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales") and make sure the code is in a standard code module.

Comment: What you have should work if it's in the same Workbook.  Are you getting an error message at all?  Also, are you changing the data going into the pivot table or are you adding?  If adding, does the Data Source extend to enough rows?  Third thought, is do you have multiple pivot tables on the "Sales" worksheet.  If so, have you tried referencing it by it's name rather than the index.

Comment: Hi @ACCtionMan, no error msg, I'm changing the data, refreshing the current day's data and the data source extend to all rows, no problem. I have only one pivot table per sheet and yes I tried index and name. What I don't understand is that if run the code within the "Sales" sheet, it works with no problem at all. Really weird, isnn't it?

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, but either way, doesnt work :-(

Comment: Not really sure what to suggest as I did a basic test spreadsheet and what you have works.  Although not best practice, you could get your macro to select the "Sales" worksheet, do the refresh, then go back to the other worksheet.

Comment: Thanks @ACCtionMan, I totally agree with you! Maybe that is the alternative! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi @ACCtionMan, I believe the issue is with the button calling, if I run the code from other worksheet not using the button it is working but when using the button doesnt it!!                                                                                                                                  the sub Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Call RefreshSales
End Sub